# sed remove line based on choice from specific field

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

Input:

```
coupon,11/2018,1
voucher,04/2018,2
```

Output:

```
coupon,11/2018,1
```

I would like to remove lines from big file where the mm/year is under `11/2018` in `$2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F '[,/]' '($3 == 2018 && $2 >= 11) || $3 > 2018' file
coupon,11/2018,1
```

Treating the input as delimited by either commas or slashes, the second field of the input will be the month and the third field will be the year.

The `awk` program prints the input if the year is 2018 and the month is greater than or equal to 11, or if the year is greater than 2018.

Doing this with `sed` would involve having to determine whether the date is before or after November 2018 using regular expressions. This is nontrivial.

A regular expression that matches any 4-digit integer that is greater than 2018:

```
[3-9][0-9]{3}|2[1-9][0-9]{2}|20[2-9][0-9]|2019
^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
3000-9999     2100-2999      2020-2099
```

So the `sed` command becomes

```
$ sed -n -E '\#(1[12]/2018)|([01][0-9]/([3-9][0-9]{3}|2[1-9][0-9]{2}|20[2-9][0-9]|2019))#p' file
coupon,11/2018,1
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU **`awk`** approach:

Sample file:

```
coupon,11/2018,1
voucher,04/2018,2
a,31/2016,b
aa,02/2019,bb
```

---

```
awk -v d=$(date +%s -d"11/01/2018") \
-F',' '{ split($2, a, "/") }mktime(sprintf("%d %d 01 00 00 00", a[2], a[1])) >= d' file
```

The output:

```
coupon,11/2018,1
aa,02/2019,bb
```